# Managing contents of SPARK_CONF_DIR on k8s

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, apache-ranger

I am using Apache Spark and Ranger on Kubernetes using cluster mode. In order to integrate Ranger with Spark, I need to add xml files in the conf dir.

The driver pod gets spun up as part of the spark submit. How can I add files to `/opt/spark/conf` which seems to be an immutable configmap that gets mounted during pod creation.